# Synaptic package manager not launching in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: package-management, synaptic, 17.10

In Ubuntu 17.04, **Synaptic Package Manager** worked fine. But after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10, it is not working. I removed it and installed it again, with no success. How do I solve this issue?